# Android Unit testing with Robolectric throws error AndroidManifest.xml not found or not a file

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

I am trying to use Robolectric to run a test case on a App in Eclipse as described in [this blog](http://digitaldumptruck.jotabout.com/?p=749), but when I run the JUnit Test, I get the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\abc\workspace\SumTestCases\AndroidManifest.xml not found or not a file; it should point to your project's AndroidManifest.xml
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createResourceLoader(RobolectricTestRunner.java:269)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setupApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:229)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.internalBeforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.methodBlock(RobolectricTestRunner.java:157)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\abc\workspace\SumTestCases\AndroidManifest.xml not found or not a file; it should point to your project's AndroidManifest.xml
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createResourceLoader(RobolectricTestRunner.java:256)
    ... 17 more
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You should run JUnit in the folder where is AndroidManifest.xml is placed
2. [You could extend RobolectricTestRunner and call parent constructor with path to the AndroidManifest.xml](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/customizing.html)

Comment: Second solution's link has expired

Comment: Are you still using Eclipse?

Comment: No, but I encounter the same issue in Android Studio

Comment: Search for similar issue for AS. You should specify working folder for unit tests correctly

Comment: Thanks for downvoting. Did you check that answer was given for Eclipse and almost three years ago?