# Testing with Robolectric in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, testing, junit4, robolectric

I am trying to run a simple test with Robolectric in **eclipse**. I followed [this](http://digitaldumptruck.jotabout.com/?p=749) tutorial, but got this error :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Vishal\Development\workspace>\AndroidHelloWorldTester.\AndroidManifest.xml not found or not a file; it >should point to your project's AndroidManifest.xml

Then as per Eugen's advice at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397445/android-unit-testing-with-robolectric-throws-error-androidmanifest-xml-not-found), I tried to extend the RobolectricTestRunner class as per instructed [here](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/customizing.html) but got this error :- (well I couldn't write the constructor exactly as directed since it was causing compilation error)

> java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor

Currently this is the class :-

```
package com.myTest;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.visd.helloworld.AndroidHelloWorldActivity;
import com.visd.helloworld.R;
import com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class Ahtest extends RobolectricTestRunner {

    public Ahtest(Class AndroidHelloWorldActivity) throws InitializationError {
    super(AndroidHelloWorldActivity, "<the project root location>");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

    private Button pressMeButton;
    private TextView results;
    AndroidHelloWorldActivity activity;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        activity = new AndroidHelloWorldActivity();

        activity.onCreate(null);
        pressMeButton = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.mybut1);
        results = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomethingMeaningfulToMyApp() {
         pressMeButton.performClick();
         String resultsText = results.getText().toString();
         assertThat(resultsText, equalTo("Button Clicked"));
    }

}
```

P.N. : 
1) I made different project for the application and for the test.
2) I could not write the constructor exactly as specified since if I specified :-

> super(testClass, new File("../other/project-root"));

I would get compilation error.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vishal,

you're mixing test and runner classes.

**junit** works in general like:

```
for (TestClass c: allTests) {
    Test t = TestClass.newInstance();

    testListener.startTest(t.getName());
    try {
       t.beforeTest();
       t.run();
       t.afterTest();

       testListener.testPass(t.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
       if (t.isExpectedException(e)) {
           testListener.testPass(t.getName());
       } else if (isAssertException(e)) {
           testListener.testFail(t.getName(), getExplanation(e));
       } else {
           testListener.testError(t.getName(), e);
       }
    }

    testListener.testEnd(t.getName());
}
```

Because of `Class.newInstance()` method call it's required to have public non-zero parameters constructor for test class. Annotations `@Test`, `@Before` and `@After` mark to **junit** which classes are test classes.

The code above is kind of test runner class. Sometimes you need additional logic from test runner class. For example **Robolectric** and **PowerMock** are replacing standard ClassLoader with own specific for purposes. **Robolectric** to provide own implementation for Android classes. **PowerMock** for ability to mock static, final classes and methods, as well for mocking classes constructors.

`@RunWith` annotation exists to notify **junit** that it should use another test runner for test class. So **Robolectric** Android test should have `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)`. However you have ability to add additional functionality to **Robolectric** test runner by extending `RobolectricTestRunner` class. For example for own shadowing or pointing to specific AndroidManifest.xml file.

So you should have your own test runner class `AHTesRunner` where you will point **Robolectric** to specific manifest file location:

```
public class AHTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {}
```

And you need to notify **junit** that it should use your own test runner (customized **Robolectric** test runner):

```
@RunWith(AHTestRunner.class)
public class AHTest {
    @Before
    ......
    @Test
    ......
    @After
}
```

Hope this is much clear now

Comment: Thanks, so I created a subclass of RobolectricTestRunner :-     `public class Ahtestrunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

 public Ahtestrunner(Class<?> C) throws InitializationError {
  super(C, "../AndroidHelloWorld");
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

}`  but now I am getting runtimeexception **error inflating layout** and also a console warning : **Unable to find path to sdk**.

Comment: Great! New issue - new question! Check you local.properties files - there should be valid path to android sdk

Comment: I had got the answer (which you have provided is the previous comment) in the web before posting my doubt as the comment. I had made a file - local.properties in the test project and also added to the environment variable. But still getting the same error: "unable to find Android-sdk". Please answer in more detail. Lack of good help resource led me to stop thinking about robolectric but I think its better to learn about this. So, please help by providing more detailed answer. Thank you.

Comment: What is inside your local.properties file? Let us go to the caht

Comment: the contents of local.properties :- `sdk.dir="..\Vishal\Development\Androidsdk\android-sdk-windows"` , I have created a room : "visdArtoo" so you can join the room for us to chat. Or else tell me your alternative how could we chat to sort out the problem. Thanks for you interest and willingness to help.